# Nginx Development vs Stable

Tags: nginx

Does anyone know the major differences between the Nginx Development and Stable editions? I know that there is a risk of bugs etc. in development. But I was more concerned with performance/features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a big nginx pro, but in my experience development version is usable enough(no chashes so far) and it also had a fixed bug with 201 response code while the stable one hang when i was trying to give 201 from the backend server. In this particular situation dev version was helpful. 
Anyway, potential risk of bugs I think is a serious reason to go and stick with stable version, even if it might be less performant.

Answer (score 0):

The "development" branch is also called "mainline".
According to Nginx (quoted repeatedly on their site, [here is one example](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-6-1-7-released/))

> Note that stable does not mean more reliable or more bug-free. In fact, the mainline is generally regarded as more reliable..
>   We recommend that in general you deploy the NGINX mainline branch at all times.

The reason to use the stable is mostly for plugins - the stable won't change anything a plugin might be relying on.

While stable is theoretically more likely to be abused by a minor bug that hasn't been back-ported, mainline is theoretically more likely to have a 0-day or overlooked bug that made it through testing and early deployment.
IMO neither of those should be part of your initial calculations. You should have a backup and ideally a rollover server in any case.